# Default content of DB tables in Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, migration

I'm learning Laravel and have got a question I can't quite figure out myself.
So for instance I have DB tables like `cities` or `car_models` and migrations for them. But I don't want to manually populate those tables each time I migrate:refresh or deploy the project on testing/production server, so they must have some default content.

Is it okay to populate them right in the migration? Or is this what seeders are for? (as far as I understood they are for populating tables with some fake data for testing needs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both answers are correct. But they're missing something important.

In my opinion, the most important value using [Seeder](https://laravel.com/docs/seeding) classes is that you decouple your migrations from your population logic.

Why is this important? You have many answers for this:

- Code quality.
- Support of a couple SOLID principles.
- Good practices.
- Better understanding of your code.
- Cleaner API.

But for me, the top one is that this lets you to have **different results for distinct porpuses using the same code**. This is an example:

You write your seeders/population logic inside migration files. What happen if you want to deploy your app in a `production` environment? Well, you'll need to modify your migrations to avoid incluiding the functions of dummy data, then commit those changes and upload them to the server. If you need to deploy it in a different environment (`staging` for example) you'll need to change this again.

Instead, if you create specific classes to populate your database ([Seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/seeding)) you have the flexibility to use the same code and include (or the opposite) them with a command flag:

```php
// The following won't include your seeders
php artisan migrate

// This will include your seeder classes
php artisan migrate --seed
```

You can be even more granular, specifying a specific seeder:

```php
php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder
```

This is helpful when you want to populate just a few tables in your environments (like `roles`, `types`, `cities` and so on) instead of running all of your seeders (`users`, `orders`, `reservations`, ...).

I hope this helps.

Comment: But if it is not dummy data, but like list of real cities that I want to be present everywhere I deploy my project? But well all the reasons except the last one make perfect sense why I should do it the second way.

Comment: @Zlautumn that is why I mentioned the last line (the granular one). I use this option when I want to populate some master tables (`cities`, `types`, etc).

Comment: now that you've pointed it out I totally got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

migration is used to create table while seeder is used to insert dummy data to table in database. You can populate them in migration but it's not a good practice and can lead to confusion.

Comment: "You can populate them in migration but it's not a good practice and can lead to confusion." Depens if the code is a update off a application or a newly created app which uses database configuration records to work a migration is pretty sound to use... Because there isn't a good version control database system out there for databases.